# Using string in referencing JSON object in request

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string

Using a fetch request to get some data. The JSON object path depends on a string variable. How would I convert the string into an object that can be referenced as an array in the path. Here's my code:

```
var path = 'bob';

fetch(request)
    .then(function(response) {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw Error(response.statusText);
        }
        return response.json();
    }).then(function(json) {

        var data = json.message.path[0].text;

    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

JSON:

```
{
"message": {
    "bob": [
      {
        "name_id": "3351",
        "name": "bob",
        "text": "lorem ipsum"
      },
      {
        "name_id": "34562",
        "name": "bob",
        "text": "lorem ipsum2"
      }
    ]
}
```

Basically, `path` defines the correct object to be used in the dot notation. BUT - the object also has to be able to reference the array.

Any solutions?

Comment: What do you mean by "the object has to be able to reference the array"? Can you give a concrete example of the structure of `json` and `path`?

Comment: The the JSON is organized, the path is an array and I need to get the first item in that array. But I can only reference the path by a string. See example code.

Comment: In your example, `path` isn't an array, it's a string... Do you mean that you get a string representing a path, which you then want to convert into an array?

Comment: Adding context/more specifics to your question will help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: Added the example JSON. Basically access 'bob' at the top level is determined by a string. But I need to be able to reference bob[0] in the object notation when I'm defining the data.

Comment: Sorry, edited example. `path = 'bob'` `path` is the variable being predefined in the code in order to reference the correct data.

Comment: OK, now it's just a direct duplicate.

Comment: But what would be the syntax for using it as an array? `json.message[path][0].text`?

Comment: Yes, that's how you use arrays. Or `var tmp = json.message[path]; ... tmp[0]` - same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using:

```
var data = json.message[path][0].text;
```

where path is the name of the object as you defined:

```
path = "bob";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `path` variable in the format `user.index`, you could reference the corresponding message in your JSON like this:

```
path = path.split(".");
var name = path[0], index = path[1];
var data = json.message[name][index].text;
```

If `path` is `"bob.1"`, `data` would become `"lorem ipsum2"`

`json.message[name]` evaluates to the array of messages. To index into that array, just put brackets after the value, like any other array: `json.message[name][index]`, which is equivalent to `(json.message[name])[index]`, which is equivalent to `var array = json.message[name]` then `array[index]`.

Note that this solution does no error checking, and will throw an error if the given user isn't in `json.message`.